# how to access values from one function to another

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function "function1" which is in "testComponent", I have another function which is "function2"  in "test2component", In function2 I have variable "a=10" I want to access that "a" value in "function1" how can I do that.

my code:

```
       test2Component
          a
          function2(post_data){
           this.service.postUser(post_data).subscribe(respone=>{
           return this.a = '10'
           });
          }

       testComponent:

       constructor(public usrcpmt : test2Component){
       console.log( this.usrcpmt.a);
       }
```

I have tried this way, the "a" value is printing Undefined

Comment: 1 Your question doesn't match the pseudo-code you show: where is function1 ? 2.Can you try to show some real TS, because it's harder to read this way...

Comment: What is relation between those components? Are they siblings?

Answer (score 0):

If test component 1 and test component 2 are parent child component :-

1. Test component 2 is parent component :- pass a as an input to test component 1 using @Input().
2. Test Component 2 is child component :- Pass as as an output to test component 1 using @Output();

If they are non-related components :-

1. Store Data in service and get it in test component 1 using subject/behaviorsubject.
2. use state management like ngrx.
3. use localStorage, sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use services for this

Services are singleton classes

Like

```
export class MyService {
      value;
      constructor() {}

      getValue() {
          return this.value;
      }

      setValue(val) {
           this.value = val;
      }
}
```

Now import this service in both your components

```
  export class test2Component {
        function2() {
           const a = 10;
           this.myService.setValue(a);
        }
  }

  export class test1Component {
       function1() {
           const valFromService = this.myService.getValue();
        }
  }
```